# Post/Redirect/Get on Struts 1

Tags: java, redirect, post, get, struts

I have a Struts 1 web application and I would like to implement post/redirect/get in order to force a redirect when the user press back/forward button on the browser. The main problem is that we want to implement a session time out. We are redirecting to a "sessionExpired" page when the session has expired, but we want to hidde the information of the previous page if the user clicks back on the browser. I have already add the code to remove the cache on the actions:

```
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "private, no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
```

But that will throw a "Not found page on the cache" of the browser, and we want to run something that redirects to a page instead of the "no cache" page. That's why I'm trying to implement PRG.

Answer (score 2):

The [Post/Redirect/Get pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) doesn't consist in forcing a redirect when the user presses the Back button. It consists in sending a redirect after a successful POST request.

In Struts 1, define the forward with `redirect="true"`, and Struts will send a redirect if you return this forward:

```
<forward name="success" path="/index.do" redirect="true"/>
```

Comment: But the Action is not going to run if we press back/forward button on the browser, so the redirect will not be sended. At least it is was happening in Firefox.

Comment: The point of the PRG pattern is precisely to avoid a resubmission of the POST request. You have a list of products, you click on "add product", you submit the form with post, and send a redirect to the list of products once the product has been created. If the user presses the Back button, it will go back to the product creation page, then to the product list, without resubmitting the product creation.

Comment: I have added more information of my problem, many thanks in any case.

Comment: The PRG pattern won't help at all to deal with this problem. It's not what you think it is. Read the linked wikipedia page.

Answer (score 0):

Set these lines on your View( Jsp page).Top of the page after your directive tags.

```
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store");
response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);
response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
```

And use `redirect="true"` in struts.

Comment: Sorry mate, same problem, although we do not recieve the "page not found in the cache", we are not running any action between de proccess of clicking back on the browser and redirecting to the page.